# Count Cell Color with Count IF critiea VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

Hey all i have a range of data i wish to count by cell color and if it contains a certain value (the month of April this year). This is my current Formula

```
=CountCcolorIF('2019-2020'!I3:AT3,'2019-2020'!I1,"15/04/2020")
```

*currently only testing it with a single date rather than an entire month*

And here is my VBA code

```
  Function CountCcolorIF(range_data As Range, criteria As Range, 
  cellvalue As Range) As Long
        Dim datax As Range
        Dim xcolor As Long
  xcolor = criteria.Interior.ColorIndex
  Application.Volatile
  For Each datax In range_data
  If datax.Interior.ColorIndex = xcolor And datax.Value = 
  cellvalue.Value Then
        CountCcolorIF = CountCcolorIF + 1
     End If
  Next datax
  End Function
```

As far as i can tell everything should be functioning how i intend it too but it's not. Could anyone offer some insight as to why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set the third variable as range. And when you pass it as string, it causes type mismatch. Your function works if you write the date in a cell and pass the address of that cell to the function.

Comment: or set cellvalue as a string and leave the rest alone

Comment: yes, that is the other end of the solution.